# Formula to find data in three different worksheets

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a data set with 3 worksheets similar to the follow:

AS400 Ref
[image]

Model Ref
[image]

Registration Ref
[image]

There are three different lists all containing roughly the same data; AS400/Model/Registrations. What I want to do is extract a unique set of zip codes from all 3 lists and put them on a master worksheet (the easy part), then what I need is something that looks at every zip code on the master page, then looks at every other page and returns the matching Branch column if it's found. Finally, on the master page I'd like to be able to determine if all 3 match, or if there is an 'odd ball' within them. This is an example of what I'm looking for:

[image]

Any suggestions of a formula I could use to return the part finding all of the zip codes. I'm at a loss and not familiar enough with excel to know where to start.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Okay, `17070` is in AS400 Ref, and its Branch is 0. I can't see it in others, so I guess it can be 0 in the others too. But `60431` has 0 in AS400 Ref but in your example, you get 474?

Comment: @Jerry Sorry for the confusion, the final output is based on the real dataset which it almost a million records total. The images are only for quick reference. I basically want it to go [Zip] for the first column, (If [zip] exists in Models then [Models].[branch Id]) for [Historical Branch], (If [zip] exists in Registration then [Registration].[branch Id]) for [registration branch], and (If [zip] exists in AS400 then [AS400].[branch Id]).

Comment: Okay, that makes it clearer now. A word of warning that the images don't match would probably have avoided that ^^. Have you already obtained the master page? You mentioned that it was easy. Also, was my assumption that if no zip was found, a branch ID of 0 is to be given, right?

Comment: Yes, that would be acceptable. Some records have 0 as a branch, but essentially that means it was entered in an old system that required a parameter no matter what ( 0 was entered by default, but not actually a branch number ).

Comment: @Jerry And yep, I have the master page, just copied all zips into one column and ran the 'remove duplicates' function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, first of all, the zip should be of the same format. If they're text in the master page, they should be text in the relevant sheets.

Next, you can use `VLOOKUP` to retrieve the Branch ID from the relevant sheets, and you'll need only 3 variations of this formula; one for each column.

I will be assuming that all your tables have the header `zip` in cell A1; so change the references if required, and that the sheets are named `AS400 Ref`, `Model Ref` and `Registration Ref`

---

In the master page, cell B2 (that's the column ModelBranch and row for 17070), use the formula:

```
=VLOOKUP($A2, 'Model Ref'!A:B, 2, 0)
```

In C2 and D2, use the formulae:

```
=VLOOKUP($A2, 'Registration Ref'!A:B, 2, 0)

=VLOOKUP($A2, 'AS400 Ref'!A:B, 2, 0)
```

You can then drag the formulae down as far down as required. This should retrieve the required Branch ID. If there is a possibility that the zip is not found, then put the whole `VLOOKUP` into an `IFERROR`. For instance, the first would become:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP($A2, 'Model Ref'!A:B, 2, 0), 0)
```

`VLOOKUP` takes the first parameter (`$A2` in this instance), looks it up in the first column of the table array and then looks into the second column (hence why the 3rd parameter is 2) for the value to retrieve, which is from column B (if the value was to be obtained from column C, then you'd use `'Model Ref'!A:C, 3`).

To get the last part now, about the match or not, you can use this:

```
=IF(AND(B2=C2,C2=D2), "Yes", "No")
```

This checks if `B2 = C2 = D2`, in which case returns `Yes`, otherwise, `No`.

Answer (score 1):

For a large data set I suggest INDEX and MATCH (and only only column at a time before replacing formulae with values):

[image: SO20664665 example]

The example is the formula for 'Historical'.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have three sheets as you have mentioned `AS400 Ref` `Model Ref` `Registration ref` and the zip codes being consolidated in the sheet named `main`. In the main sheet on the `registrationbranch` column (which in my reference is `column b` in `main` sheet) use the `Vlookup` formula

```
=IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP($A2,'AS400 Ref'!$A$2:$B$16,2,0)),"",VLOOKUP($A2,'AS400 Ref'!$A$2:$B$16,2,0))
```

Similarly in the `AS400BRANCH` and `ALLMATCH` columns (which in my example is `Column C and Colunm D` use these formula respectively

```
=IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP($A2,'Model Ref'!$A$2:$B$16,2,0)),"",VLOOKUP($A2,'Model Ref'!$A$2:$B$16,2,0))

=IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP($A2,'Registration ref'!$A$2:$B$16,2,0)),"",VLOOKUP($A2,'Registration ref'!$A$2:$B$16,2,0))
```

Note that you need to change the reference form `A2 to B16` based on your data in different sheets.

Here is the structure of the main sheet for your refrence[image]